# Use basename to parse a list of paths held in a file

Tags: find, osx, filenames, duplicate, basename

I'm running Mac OSX and trying to use the command line to find the number of files I have with the same name.

I tried to use the following command:

```
find ~ -type f -name "*" -print | basename | sort | uniq -d > duplicate_files
```

It doesn't work! When I do the following:

```
find ~ -type f -name "*" -print > duplicate_files
```

Then duplicate_files does contain the paths of all my files. So I think the issue is with `basename` - it doesn't accept standard input. I then tried the following:

```
basename $(find ~ -type f -name "*" -print) > duplicate_files
```

but again that doesn't seem to work. Search on the internet doesn't seem to yield much joy. Any thoughts most welcome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`basename` operates on its command line argument, it doesn't read from standard input.

You don't need to call the `basename` utility, and you'd better not: all it would do is strip off the part before the last `/`, and it would be slow to call an external command for each entry, you can use a text processing utility instead.

```
find ~ -type f | sed 's!.*/!!' | sort | uniq -d
```

It may be more useful to keep track of the location of the files. Sorting by name makes it easier to locate duplicates, but `sort` doesn't have an option to use the last field. What you can do is copy the last `/`-separated field to the beginning, then sort, and then use a bit of ad hoc awk processing to extract and present the duplicates.

```
find ~ -type f |
sed 's!.*/\(.*\)!\1/&!' |   # copy the last field to the beginning
sort -t/ -k1,1 |
cut -d/ -f2- |   # remove the extra first field (could be combined with awk below)
awk -F / '{
    if ($NF == name) {
        if (previous != "") {print previous; previous = ""}
        print
    } else {
        previous = $0
        name = $NF
    }
'
```

(Note that I assume that none of your file names contain newline characters.)

Comment: Super thanks. This is exactly what I was trying to do ... very useful

Answer (score 9):

Why not to use builtin `find` features to output just filename:

```
find ~ -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

(assumes GNU `find`) or at least something like this:

```
find ~ -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq -c
```

`basename` can't read via pipe or process multiple files at once.

ps. There is no need to specify `-name '*'` if you want to list all the files. This is a default option.

Comment: Thanks -- '-printf' doesn't work for OS X UNIX

Comment: And when I try the second version I get `basename: unknown primary or operator`. Thanks for the tip on `-name "*"`

Comment: That's strange. I can see `-printf` even in posix man page. About the error with second way, it's cause of typo in my answer. Fixed. Could you please try it one more time?

Comment: Also with `-printf` I get the `-printf: unknown primary or operator`. Also when I checked the Unix in a Nutshell reference book it lists as a GNU/Linux option - doesn't say anything about OSX

Comment: Actually the best source would be `man find` in your console :)

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work for me on OSX:

```
find ~ -type f -exec basename -a {} + | sort | uniq -d
```

Comment: Yes - this is great thanks -- out of interest what does the `+` signify in the command?

Comment: Is this is useful please consider up-voting it.

Comment: It is  -- I cannot vote up beacuase i need 15 reputation :-(

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: According to the [man page for BSD basename](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=basename), the executable can take multiple strings as arguments. I double checked on OSX, it works.

Comment: All right sorry, I stand corrected. I wasn't aware of that BSD extension. However, that still fails if there are exactly two files. You'd need to add the [`-a` option](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/basename.1.html) to cover for that case as well.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Good point. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives (assumes no newline in file names):

```
find ~ -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -d
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xargs` with `basename` to get the desired output, like this:

```
find ~ -type f -name "*" -print | xargs -l basename | sort | uniq -d > duplicate_files
```

Answer (score 0):

With a recent version of `bash` that handles associative arrays, the following would additionally handle pathnames with embedded newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash

topdir=$HOME

shopt -s globstar  # enable the ** glob

declare -A count

# count the number of times each filename (base name) occurs
for pathname in "$topdir"/**; do
    # skip names that are not regular files (or not symbolic links to such files)
    [ ! -f "$pathname" ] && continue

    # get the base name
    filename=${pathname##*/}

    # add one to this base name's count
    count[$filename]=$(( ${count[$filename]} + 1 ))
done

# go through the collected names and print any name that
# has a count greater than one
for filename in "${!count[@]}"; do
    if [ "${count[$filename]}" -gt 1 ]; then
        printf 'Duplicate filename: %s\n' "$filename"
    fi
done
```

This uses no external utility.